# Analytic number theory and condensed mathematics

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, condensed-mathematics

As of 2024, are there current or planned applications of condensed mathematics to analytic number theory? If so, what are suggested readings?

Comment: Real local Langlands presumably counts as analytic number theory (since it's relevant to number theory and involves analysis) and there's planned work on that, which could eventually give a formulation of the real local Langlands correspondence that predicts not just which irreducible representations exist but extensions between representation. There is not much to read on this yet.

Comment: @WillSawin I agree completely that condensed math should provide a (very welcome) form of local Langlands that handles “big” representations, such as appear eg in harmonic analysis, but as for extensions (so finite length representations) there is already Soergel’s conjecture refining the K theoretic results of Adams Barbasch Vogan..

Comment: Any links on what "condensed mathematics" means?

Comment: @Gerald Edgar: for a first intuition, see Scholze's answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4044728/examples-of-the-difference-between-topological-spaces-and-condensed-sets. Then there are now several sets of lecture notes online, e.g. this recent book and references therein https://perso.univ-rennes1.fr/bernard.le-stum/bernard.le-stum/Enseignement_files/CondensedBook.pdf

Comment: @WillSawin I think a lot of analytic number theorists would consider your definition of analytic number theory to be overly broad (not necessarily myself)

Comment: @StanleyYaoXiao Using those two criteria as an argument that something is analytic number theory is not quite the same as saying that everything satisfying the two criteria is analytic number theory or defining analytic number theory by those two criteria.